# Combinatorics: calcaulating number of sections of an hesse diagrem, (help with sigma).

Tags: combinatorics

in this picture you can see the hesse diagrem of $\subseteq$ over $P(\{x,y,z\})$

[image]

it has 12 sections.

for the set $A$ with $k$ elements, $k>0$

find the numbers of sections in the hesse diagrem of $\subseteq$ over $P(A)$

I need help with this question, if I understood it right it should be:

$\binom {k} {k} * \binom {k}{k-1} + \binom {k}{k-1}* \binom {k-1}{k-2} +...+\binom {k}{1}* \binom {1}{0}$

is it correct? how do I write it's sigma? if someone can help me write it's sigma it would help me a lot since I think even after seeing a lot of sigmas in other solved excercises, after spending a while on this question, I would actually take the time to understand it.

Comment: Your formula with sigma: $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom{k}{k-i}\binom{k-i}{k-i-1}$ or $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\binom{k}{i}\binom{i}{i-1}$
wich can both can be simplified because $\binom{r}{r-1}=r$ for a
positive integer $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{k}{i}$ sets that have exactly $i$ elements. If
you pick one of these sets then there are $k-i$ sets that contain
this set and have exactly $1$ element more. This leads to formula:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}\left(k-i\right)=k2^{k-1}$$

I am not familiar with 'sections of Hesse diagrams' so please forgive me if this is a wrong track.